# Sort a text file where each line is a name followed by a score

Tags: c#, xna

I'm going to make a scoreboard for an XNA game but I'm having some trouble figuring out how. The player, after finishing a level, will enter his name when prompted. His name and time will be recorder in a text file something like this:

```
sam 90
james 64
matthew 100
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to sort this data by the time taken only and not taking into account the name.

I haven't started coding this yet but if anybody can give me any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the file into memory, split each line into name / number, sort by number.  If you get stuck - post how far you got.

Comment: also separate fields by a delimiter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, read the text file using `File.ReadAllLines(...)` so you get a string array. Then iterate over the array and split each string on blank space (assuming users can't enter spaces in their names) and order on the second element, which should be the score. You have to cast it into a string with `int.Parse(...)` to be able to order it properly.

```
string[] scores = File.ReadAllLines("scorefile.txt");
var orderedScores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[1]));

foreach (var score in orderedScores)
{
    Console.WriteLine(score);
}
//outputs:
//matthew 100
//sam 90
//james 64
```

I would recommend using something like a semi-colon to separate the name and the score instead of a space, as that makes it much easier to handle in the case that users are allowed to enter spaces in their names.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this definitely seems like the most efficient and elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make this into a database file, .sdf which you can easily create on the fly if needed. Would be best for keeping track of data allowing sorting and future reuse.

SQLite is designed for this exact purpose, makes basic CRUD operations a doddle. You can also encrypt database files if your game grows and you want to start using it as a way to download/upload high scores and share scores with friends/world.

Don't get me wrong, this is definitely a little more work than simply parsing a text file, but it is future proof and you get a lot of functionality right out of the bag without having to write parsers and complex search routines etc.

XML is a definite other choice, or JSON. All 3 are all good alternatives. A plain text file probably isn't the way to go though, as in the end will probably cause you more work.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't think of that. Thanks for the help, this should make it easier to pull of :]

Comment: SQL is a bit overkill for something as simple as a score file with two fields if you ask me. I considered mentioning an XML file but even that felt a bit too heavy for this type of simple data record. This of course depends on if you intend to use the score data in a multitude of ways.

Comment: SQLite is designed for this exact purpose, fast easy CRUD operations. It will be more future proof if the game expands and he wants to keep more information in. Agree that XML is also a good alternative, especially for download/upload purposes

Comment: I'm not arguing about the overhead of the SQL server architecture (a server, a SQL CE file etc..) but about the code overhead in interfacing with SQL using either SqlCommand or something like LINQ2SQL. For a thing this simple it will just complicate things for no reason whatsoever. But I *do* agree that it would be more future proof with an embedded SQL db.

Answer (score 0):

Create the score table as

```
name::score
```

and read every line and on it

```
string line = "Sam::255";
string name = line.split("::")[0];
```

Also do similar to the score.